# Should my java application be opening two instances of java.exe?

Tags: java, multiple-instances

I noticed while debugging an issue that my application opens two instances of Java.exe at the start. I also noticed my 'main' class (see pic) has two run icons (green triangles) and maybe I somehow assigned two runs. This may be the cause but I suspect my application shouldn't be launching two instances of Java.exe to run. I was wondering what I may need to do to resolve this issue? What I may have accidentally done to cause it?

I using Intellij IDEA version 2019.1.1 and Java 1.8.0_202. This is a JavaFX application.

[image: Two Instances of Java for a Single Application]

Comment: Intellij IDEA itself is a Java application. The green triangles are not the cause of this behavior.  Running two Java applications is the cause

Comment: Ah, ok! I didn't think about Intellij being a Java application, I guess I had a dense moment.